# Why am I not getting an expected output using logical operators and indexing?

Tags: python-3.x, binary, byte, addition

I am having trouble achieving an expected output. I am trying to create a byte adder using logical operators such as AND, XOR and OR. I have taken the minimal code required to reproduce the problem out of code, so assume that `finalfirstvalue = "1010"` and `finalsecondvalue = "0101"`.

```
secondvalueindex = (len(finalsecondvalue) - 1)
carry, finalans = False, []
for i in range(-1, -len(finalfirstvalue) - 1, -1):
    andone = (bool(finalfirstvalue[i])) & (bool(finalsecondvalue[secondvalueindex]))
    xorone = (bool(finalfirstvalue[i])) ^ (bool(finalsecondvalue[secondvalueindex]))
    andtwo = (bool(carry)) & (bool(xorone))
    xortwo = (bool(carry)) ^ (bool(xorone))
    orone = (bool(andone)) | (bool(andtwo))
    carry = (bool(orone))
    finalans.append(xortwo)
    secondvalueindex -= 1

answer = ''.join(str(e) for e in finalans)
print (answer)
```

Actual Output: `FalseTrueTrueTrue`
Expected Output: `TrueTrueTrueTrue`

The code then follows to change back into zeroes and ones.

Because its missing a single boolean I feel like the issue is with my indexing. Although I've played around with it a bit and not had any luck.

I need to carry out these operations on the two variables mentioned at the start, but for the right most elements, and then move to the left by one for the next loop and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mistake is You are representing your binary numbers as string values.

`finalfirstvalue = "1010"`
`finalsecondvalue = "0101"`

`secondvalueindex = (len(finalsecondvalue) - 1)` `==` `3`

So in second for loop you will get the result as

`(finalsecondvalue[secondvalueindex])` `==` `'0'`

If you check in your Idle

```
>>> bool('0')
True
>>>
```

Because `'0'` is not actual 0 it is an non-empty string so it return True.

You need to cast your result to `int` before checking them with `bool`

Like this

`(bool(int(finalsecondvalue[secondvalueindex])))`

**EDIT 2**  Adding with variable lenghts

Full adder with verification using `bin()` function

```
a="011101"
b="011110"
if a>b:
    b=b.zfill(len(a))
if a<b:
    a=a.zfill(len(b))
finalfirstvalue = a
finalsecondvalue = b
carry, finalans = 0, []
secondvalueindex = (len(finalsecondvalue))

for i in reversed(range(0, len(finalfirstvalue))):
    xorone = (bool(int(finalfirstvalue[i]))) ^ (bool(int(finalsecondvalue[i])))
    andone = (bool(int(finalfirstvalue[i]))) & (bool(int(finalsecondvalue[i])))
    xortwo = (carry) ^ (xorone)
    andtwo = (carry) & (xorone)

    orone = (andone) | (andtwo)
    carry = (orone)
    finalans.append(xortwo)


finalans.reverse()
answer=(''.join(str(e) for e in finalans))
print(str(carry)+answer)
print(bin(int(a,2) + int(b,2)))    #verification
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, it seems to of only part solved the problem. I think something may be wrong with my choosing of logical operators. The inputs I can give to get an expected output seem to be quite random. Upon further investigation, wouldn't changing to `int` cause problems in some cases? If a binary value starts with zero, the first zero will be discarded- which would explain why some of the results appear to be quite random.

Comment: @AugustWilliams Yes I am working on that and i will update.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I am also working on fixes too.

Comment: @AugustWilliams Hope it's working now , Check the updated answer.

Comment: You need to print the carry too at the LSB, if it resolves the your problem then you can accept it.

Comment: I am so grateful for the effort you have put into this for me. Funnily enough, I came up with my own solution and fix at the very moment I got this notification on stack overflow. I implemented your solution into my program and everything seems to be working as expected. I find both methods quite interesting actually - I will use both in my final program. Thank you so much for your help. Im about to post an answer here to show my solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127830/discussion-between-rakesh-k-and-august-williams).

Comment: @AugustWilliams  you can post your own solution that would be great, and by the way now I am working with variable inputs (if both inputs are not of the same lenght)
All i have to do is add leading 0's to the smaller number

Answer (score 1):

So I found the issue was to do with `carry`. I changed my code to look like the following. Prior to this code below, is code to convert binary values to boolean. For instance, all ones will equal `True` and all zeroes will equal `False`.

```
carry, finalans = False, []
indexvalue = (len(finalfirstvalue)-1)
while indexvalue >= 0:
    andone = (firstvaluelist[indexvalue]) & (secondvaluelist[indexvalue])
    xorone = (firstvaluelist[indexvalue]) ^ (secondvaluelist[indexvalue])
    andtwo = (carry) & (xorone)
    xortwo = (carry) ^ (xorone)
    orone = (andone) | (andtwo)
    carry = (orone)
    if (carry == True) & (indexvalue == 0):
        finalans.append(xortwo)
        finalans.append(True)
    else:
        finalans.append(xortwo)
    indexvalue -= 1

for n, i in enumerate(finalans):
    if i == False:
        finalans[n] = "0"
    if i == True:
        finalans[n] = "1"

finalans.reverse()
answer = ''.join(str(e) for e in finalans)
print (answer)
```

So if there was a single value missing, it was still stored in `carry` from the final loop but did not get the opportunity to be appended to the final result. To fix this, I added in an `if` statement to check if `carry` is containing anything (`True`) and if the loop is on its final loop by checking if `indexvalue` is at `0`. This way, if the inputs are `32` and `32`, rather than getting `[False, False, False, False, False, False]` as the output, the newly entered `if` statement will add the missing value in.